# remix fetch data within a loader from another loader

Tags: remix.run

Trying to fetch data internally within remix application
from an api route located in

```
/routes/api/test.tsx
```

```typescript
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const testRes = await fetch("/api/test");
  return await testRes.json();
};
```

I get error Invalid URL
what is the right convention for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call another URL you have to pass in the full url. Something like:

```js
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const testRes = await fetch("https://example.com/api/test");
  return await testRes.json();
};
```

To have the domain be dynamically set you could use the URL from the request. Something like this:

```js
export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
  const domain = new URL(request.url).hostname;

  const testRes = await fetch(`${domain}/api/test`);
  return await testRes.json();
};
```

Comment: why isn't there a way to call a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do something like this:

```
import {loader as anotherLoader} from './another-route';

export const loader: LoaderFunction = async (args) => {
  return await anotherLoader({...args, params: {...}})
}
```

then you just adjust the args you want to send to it